# Hyperlink to open pdf file with variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables, hyperlink

I'm currently trying to open an pdf file with variable
There a list of product name, you click on the name and it will open the appropriate pdf file
Its mean that you have to access in a folder, then from the name of the product, you find the pdf file and open it

Here is my code

```
    Sub OpenFile()

    Dim filename As String
    filename = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
    
    'If cell is empty, it don't open nothing
    If filename = "" Then
       Exit Sub
    Else
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("Y:\Logistics\MSDS" & WorksheetFunction.Text(filename) & ".pdf")
```

The file name i want to open is "1.MSDS-BETACLEAN™ 3510_VN_VN"

The error is in `WorksheetFunction.Text(filename)`, i try to replace it with `Workbooks.Open filename` and `Dir(filename, vbDirectory)` but it still didn't work

Comment: What's the value/formula of `ActiveCell`? and the full path of the file you want to open? I doubt you need to use `Text` method.

Comment: The formula of `ActiveCell` is string and number

Comment: And the full path i want to open is "Y:\Logistics\MSDS\filename"

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "Y:\Logistics\MSDS\" & filename & ".pdf"`, This is assuming `filename` is the exact filename of whatever pdf you wants to open. @DongKha you probably also want `filename = ActiveCell.Value`

Comment: @RaymondWu i've tried it, but it show the error "File name or  class name not found during Automation operator"

Comment: Without example of a cell value/formula and the file path that you want to open, it's hard to help you any further so please edit your question and provide those details. Also `Debug.Print "Y:\Logistics\MSDS\" & filename & ".pdf` and see if the output in immediate window is a valid and correct path to the file @DongKha

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu thanks for your great support, the file name i want to open is "The file name i want to open is "1.MSDS-BETACLEAN™ 3510_VN_VN"

Comment: I add Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink("Y:\0302_Logistics\MRP\20.TDS-MSDS" & filename & ".pdf") , the program highlight FollowHyperlink and said it "Compile error: Expected function or variable"

Comment: and what is the value for the cell? so the full path of the file is `"Y:\Logistics\MSDS\1.MSDS-BETACLEAN™ 3510_VN_VN.pdf`? Also, it's `Debug.Print "Y:\0302_Logistics\MRP\20.TDS-MSDS" & filename & ".pdf`

Comment: Yes, the full path is ""Y:\Logistics\MSDS\1.MSDS-BETACLEAN™ 3510_VN_VN.pdf". Also, i run Debug.Print "Y:\0302_Logistics\MRP\20.TDS-MSDS" & filename & ".pdf and nothing happen

Comment: So what is the value of the cell for that file?? The output of the `Debug.Print` is in the immediate window (Press Ctrl+G in the VB Editor to open the immediate window), check the output in the window and compare to the full path.

Comment: Thank you so much @Raymond Wu , i fix the error and i'm able to open the file now, but the file close immediately after open :(

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue with that, step through the code line by line and try to figure out what's causing it. If you are still stuck then post a new question (with all the details right from the start!)

Comment: @Raymond Wu Really grateful for your help

Comment: I recommend that you google for guide on how to debug VBA, your issue can be detected easily once you know how to debug your code.